# Hmailserver and Outlook 2013 can send but not receive any emails in POP3 or IMAP

Tags: email-server, windows-server-2012-r2, imap, pop3, outlook-2013

**I'm having problems receiving any email from outlook.**

I can send email through smtp using comcast (my isp) without a problem, but I can't receive any email using either personal pop3 configured in hmailserver or the imap from my isp.

**If anyone can help, pleas read the following descriptions of my setup and what I've done to try to fix the problem:**

> I'm running a Windows Server 2012r2 with ISS, SMTP server installed,
>   Hmailserver installed, PHP, Mysql, Squirrelmail and Outlook 2013. My
>   domain is corretcly configured and running out of my server. I have A
>   records and Mx records configured, firewall ports open for the
>   selected ports, my ISP is Comcast

**Hmailserver is configured for**

> **SMTP: port 465** [587 also works] (25 is blocked by isp)
>
> **POP3: port 110** [995 also works] 
>   -- I've created an external POP3 account on my admin@mydomain.com IP port 110, Connection SSL/TLS]
>
> **IMAP: port 993** [143 also works]

**Outlook 2013 Setup**

> **POP3 test:**
>
> Server information Incoming mail server: **mydomain.com**
>
> Outgoing mail server: smtp.comcast.net
>
> Username:admin
>
> password:*****
>
> *under more settings:*
>
> My outgoing server is checked
>
> Log on: using comcast username and password
>
> Under Advanced  Pop3: port 110 and SMTP port 465  SSL encrypted
>   connection
>
> **IMAP test:**
>
> Server information Incoming mail server: imap.comcast.net
>
> Outgoing mail server: smtp.comcast.net
>
> Username:comcast username
>
> password:*****
>
> *under more settings:*
>
> My outgoing server is checked
>
> Log on: using comcast username and password
>
> Under Advanced  IMAP: port 993 SSL and SMTP port 465  SSL encrypted
>   connection

**In Conclusion:**

The test connections are positive. I can send, but I dont get any email.

When I run an Hmailserver diagnostic everyhting passes except for the smtp because it test in port 25

Telnet mydomain.com 465 or any other port returns no errors

**I've been doing this all week, but no matter what I do. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. So please, if you know what's wrong with my setup or have any idea why I can't receive mail in either imap or pop3 in outlook. Please let me know.**

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you're saying but if you're saying that your email server isn't receiving email from external senders then it's because of port 25 being blocked. Other email servers are going to connect to your server via port 25, not ports 465 or 587. Ports 465 and 587 are client submission ports (MSA) and aren't used by other SMTP servers (MTA) when sending email to your domain.

Comment: So what are my options? My isp: comcast actively blocks port 25. If I can send email through other ports, why can't I receive email ?

Comment: What are your options? Get a different ISP. Why can't you receive email through other ports? Because email servers don't send email to the MSA ports (465 and 587), they send email to the MTA port (25).

Answer (score 1):

If you run an nmap on the record, mail.mydomain.com is the port 143 listed as an open port ? 143 is the default imap account port. For you to receive emails, both parts need to be listed as open.
Run a telnet mail. mydomain.com 110/143

Comment: I receive a Ok+Pop3 when I run Telnet mydomain.com

Comment: So doesnt it mean that is an open port?

Comment: You received an OK when you telnet to the 110 ? The port 143 has to be added to Hmail under ports

Comment: Yes, I've already tried adding both ports to hmail server, but I still can't receive an email in outlook. Everything seems to be working fine, but my email seems to not be delivered. Is comcast to blame?

Comment: Your outlook configuration on incoming points to mail.mydomian.com ? Think it's unlikely the standard Imap and pop3 ports for incoming are blocked. Is SSL installed? ?

Comment: When I connect via Pop3 the incoming mail server is mail.mydomain and when I run the test everything passes

Comment: SSL is not installed. But on Outlook I check on use the following type of connection ssl. As well as tick on the option: My outgoing server requires authentication. IS that what you mean?

Comment: Don't use SSL,there in an option in Outlook that let's you choose whether to use SSL or not, in the initial account set up.

Answer (score 0):

do not forget about mx records so that dns resolvers could find it